# Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations with assigning self as parent

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am getting the error below when I try to assign itself as the parent on an insert.

> Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values.

Code is below.  I thought I could do this but I guess not.  How can I do this on an insert?

```
public class Team {

    public int? TeamParentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TeamParentId")]
    public virtual Team TeamParent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }
}
```

**Where error happens**

```
    divisionTeam.Team.TeamParent = divisionTeam.Team;

 if (divisionTeam.Id == 0)
            {
                _divisionTeamsRepository.Add(divisionTeam);
            }

            UnitOfWork.Commit();
```

**DataContext.cs**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Team>()
    .HasOptional(p => p.TeamParent)
    .WithMany(p => p.Teams)
    .HasForeignKey(q => q.TeamParentId);
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: what is the actual question here: Why am I getting this error? or How can I set the entity to be its own parent with EF?

Comment: I state at the end of the post on how I can accomplish it.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the way you are setting the teams you are creating a cycle, which is "impossible" to "save" by EF.

If your asking about how yo can actually accomplish this then you'd have to actually save the `Team` with no parent and after the `SaveChanges()` method assign its `Id` to `TeamParentId`, like this:

```
var team = new Team(....);

db.Teams.Add(team);

team.TeamParentId = team.Id;

db.SaveChanges();
```

I know it seems convoluted enough, but it's the only way I can think of. Hope this helps you

Comment: Yea I know how to do that but I though you could do it this way also but I guess not.  I would have to do SaveChanges twice.

Comment: Also this article suggests it can be done. http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2011/06/03/how-to-configure-a-self-referencing-entity-in-code-first/

Comment: SaveChanges() uses single-row inserts, and SQL Server and most databases enforce Foreign Keys after each statement.  So there are scenarios where you must use optional foreign keys, and connect the entities is a subsequent SaveChanges().

Comment: Archive link for the blog link by @MikeFlynn 
 https://web.archive.org/web/20191230072818/http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2011/06/03/how-to-configure-a-self-referencing-entity-in-code-first/

Answer (score 0):

1) go to *.tt POCO generator file

2) Find text "ForeignKeyFilter"

3) Set

```
ForeignKeyFilter = (ForeignKey fk) =>
{
    if (fk.FkTableName == fk.PkTableName)
       return null;
    return fk;
};
```

The referenced record and collection will not be generated to result type (then it cannot be used in code). Foreign key items are still there. The INSERT will be OK.